# Supplying weights to nn.functional.conv2d in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to learn the weights of a 3x3 conv2d layer accepting 3 channels and outputting 3 channels. For this discussion consider bias=0 in each case. However, the weights of the conv layer are learned indirectly. I have a 2 layered Multi layer perception having 9 nodes in first layer and 9 in the second. The weights of the 2d conv layer are then precisely the weights learned using this MLP i.e. `nn.Linear(9,9)`. I understand in this case I will have to use `nn.functional.conv2d(input,weight)`. But how exactly to extract the weights from MLP and use it for convolution is not clear and can think of the following.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        m=nn.Linear(9,9)
    def forward(self, x):
        # some operations involving MLP `m`
        return nn.Functional.conv2d(x,m.weight)
```

Can some one provide a short, dummy code in PyTorch to achieve this training configuration allowing backpropagation?

Answer (score 2):

A convolution from 3 input channels to 3 output channels with `kernel_size=3` has 81 weights (and not 9). You can reduce this number to 27 if you use `groups=3`.

you can do the following:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.hyper = nn.Linear(9, 9)  # output the required number of parameters

  def forward(self, x):
    # do stuff with self.hyper(x)  
    y = nn.Functional.conv2d(x, self.hyper.weight.reshape((3, 3, 3, 3)))  # add padding and other parameters
    return y
```

Comment: In this solution the o/p of MLP is made weights of conv layer which is NOT what I am looking for. The weights of MLP becomes weights of conv something like `self.hyper.weights`. Thus, `nn.Linear(9,9)` is correct.

Comment: @MohitLamba please see my update. You might run into some difficulties in training this (going twice through nodes in the computation graph...) It might require using some non-default flags for `backward`.